# AttributeError: class Frame has no attribute 'tk'

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing my own Library, so I can use some functions later faster and easier. At the moment, I am working with python's GUI Library Tkinter. (`from tkinter include *`)

```
def guiFrameNew(title, width, height):
        guitmp = Tk();
        return guitmp;

def guiTextboxReadonlyNew(frame, width, text):
        guitmp = Entry(Frame, state="readonly", textvariable=text, width=width);
        guitmp.pack();
        return guitmp;

def guiFrameRun(frame):
        frame.mainloop();
```

This all is in one file (file_one.py).

In an other file (file_two.py) i included this file:

```
include file_one as f
```

Code in file_two is:

```
main = f.guiFrameNew("Test", 0, 0);
main_tbro = f.guiTextboxReadonlyNew(main, 20, "Some Text");
f.guiFrameRun(main);
```

Yes, I know that I don't need the values `Title, width, height` in `def guiFrameNew` because the function does not create a frame.

After I started the file_two.py the python Interpreter says:

```
> File "file_two", line 5, in <module>
>     main_tbro = f.guiTextboxReadonlyNew(main, 20, "Some Text");   File "/Users/MyUsername/Documents/py/file_two.py", line 190, in
> guiTextboxReadonlyNew
>     guitmp = Entry(Frame, state="readonly", textvariable=text, width=width);   File
> "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py",
> line 2447, in __init__
>     Widget.__init__(self, master, 'entry', cnf, kw)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py",
> line 2027, in __init__
>     BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py",
> line 2005, in _setup
>     self.tk = master.tk AttributeError: class Frame has no attribute 'tk'
```

I don't know why, because the function `def guiTextboxReadonlyNew(...)` is similar to the function

```
def guiTextboxNew(frame, width):
        guitmp = Entry(frame, width=width);
        guitmp.pack();
        return guitmp;
```

and `def guiTextboxNew(...)` works!

What is wrong in my file?

Comment: `guitmp = Entry(Frame, state="readonly", textvariable=text, width=width);` : replace Frame with frame...

Comment: What is this? What `include` mean here?

Comment: @Clodion The standard python `include`. You use this when you want to use Math for example: `include Math`. Or `include tkinter`;

Comment: @EricLevieil Oh! Yes thank you! I ever have problems like this. One day....... I have a problem, which is a real problem. Not only a problem between "f" and "F".

Comment: @MaxiPower98: Well, I don't have seen this before: `from tkinter include *`. Well a new thing for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assumming by `include` you mean `import` (which is really the case, since you are able to import the module `file_one`).

The `Entry()` takes a frame object as the first argument, not the `Frame` class. You should do -

```
def guiTextboxReadonlyNew(frame, width, text):
        guitmp = Entry(frame, state="readonly", textvariable=text, width=width)
        guitmp.pack()
        return guitmp
```

Also, there is not really any need for `;` (semi-colon) in python after statements.